# Listing syntax highlighting of keywords after assignation

Tags: spacing, languages, syntax-highlighting

I am using the following snippet to define a custom language:

```
\newcommand\mscript{customMATLAB}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lstdefinelanguage%
\expandafter{\mscript}{
alsoletter={:,=},
morekeywords={find_system,delete_line,...},% 
sensitive=t,%
morecomment=[l]//,%
morestring=[b]'
}
```

However when I use the language as below, only in line 1 the `find_system` is highlighted. I am assuming the space plays an important part on the syntax highlighting but I don't know how to configure the language or syntax highlighting to ignore the spaces after the assignment operator.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=customMatlab]
sys = find_system('x') 
sys=find_system('x') 
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: The `=` character is declared as a letter with `alsoletter`, so `sys=find_system` would be similar to for example `sysxfind_system`, which would also not be highlighted. If you remove `=` from `alsoletter` the second line should be highlighted as well.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn! It works 

Answer (score 1):

As @Marijn kindly suggested, the key was to remove the `=` from the `alsoletter`.